# Python: How do I print specific items from a list in an API

Tags: python, api

Im trying to print a specific number from a game API. Here is a bit of the API:

```
stats: [
{
name: "wins",
record: 3333
},
{
name: "tokens",
record: 234
},
{
name: "healing",
record: 188
},
{
name: "consumed_healing_tokens",
record: 15
}
```

I have tried:

```
response = requests.get('API')

data = response.json()

print('Healing tokens consumed:',data['stats'][3]['record'])
```

And it works on some players. But the problem is the [3] because some players has more records and others so im wondering if there is a way of pulling consumed_healing_tokens in another way. i cant do  `print(data['consumed_healing_tokens'])` because its a response

Answer (score 4):

How about converting the stats to a dict?

```
stats = {entry['name']: entry['record'] for entry in data['stats']}
print('Healing tokens consumed:', stats.get('consumed_healing_tokens'))
```

Comment: The modification done by @Gabip implies that we expect `None` to be returned if no such entry can be found. I intented to get a `KeyError` using the standard way to access dict entries using `[]`, which I found to be more pythonic. Either way one needs a strategy to cope with missing entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method to find the applicable entry in the dict:

```py
consumed_healing_tokens = next(filter(lambda stat: stat['name'] =="consumed_healing_tokens", data["stats"]))
print(consumed_healing_tokens['record'])
```